# Что значит класс определяет метод?

Tags: java

Что значит класс определяет метод?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы

Comment: Выше Вам дали совершенно правильный совет, однако ИМХО, Ваш вопрос по делу, поэтому нейтрализую поставленный Вам минус. Очень коротко - класс определяет метод - это значит, что программирование идет от данных, а не от функций. Сначала Вы определяете классы сущностей и лишь потом общие способы (методы) работы в построенной Вами иерархии классов.

Comment: пожалуйста, укажите контекст, где вам попалась эта терминология

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AnyClass{

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Класс AnyClass определяет метод start");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что в классе определяется метод поведения объекта этого класса.

Comment: пожалуйста, расширте ваш ответ, приведите пример кода